# How to use a percentage character in the Exec line of a desktop entry file

Tags: command-line, configuration

How can I use a percentage character in the Exec line of a .desktop file? The following example does not execute.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=vinagre
Name=RDP
Exec=/usr/bin/rdesktop -g 90%x90% SomeHostName
```

Comment: My standard advice on any extraordinary stuff to be done in the Exec line: Use a script.

Answer (score 3):

Use two percentage characters.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=vinagre
Name=RDP
Exec=/usr/bin/rdesktop -g 90%%x90%% SomeHostName
```

Desktop Entry Specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html